# Как сделать скролл по нажатию на меню до блока плавно не перескакивая?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Есть сайт vavlockb.bget.ru, который использует плагин https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js. У него есть меню справа от этого же плагина. При скролле вниз/вверх происходит смена слайдов и анимация некоторых элементов. Проблема в том, что при клике на элемент меню, например, 4-й, если ты находишься на 1-м, происходит переброс на блок с пропуском 2,3 блока, из-за чего нарушается вся структура, т.к. переброс не последовательный.

**Как сделать, чтобы скролл происходил плавно, с сохранением последовательности?**
Место в коде в файле jquery.fullPage.js, которое отвечает за скролл нашел, но знаний не хватает разобраться в этом.

Часть кода отвечающая за скролл по клику:

```
/**
        * Scrolls to the section when clicking the navigation bullet
        */
        $document.on('click touchstart', SECTION_NAV_SEL + ' a', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var index = $(this).parent().index();
            scrollPage($(SECTION_SEL).eq(index));
        });
    /**
            * Scrolls the slider to the given slide destination for the given section
            */
            $document.on('click touchstart', SLIDES_NAV_LINK_SEL, function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var slides = $(this).closest(SECTION_SEL).find(SLIDES_WRAPPER_SEL);
                var destiny = slides.find(SLIDE_SEL).eq($(this).closest('li').index());

                landscapeScroll(slides, destiny);
            });
```

Comment: пожалуйста, приведите пример того, что нашли, внеся исправление в вопрос с помощью кнопки [edit].

Answer (score 2):

```
var scrollTo = $('your_block').offset().top
$('body,html').animate({'scrolltop':scrollTo}, 500)
```